# php seems to automatically url decode...How can I prevent this:

Tags: php

Request POST (via javascript)
giftcard_number:%120213001?

[image: Request]

Response
0213001?

[image: Response]

It seems %12 is being converted to nothing.

NOTE: I am using the codeingiter framework and have tried turning off global xss filter and accessing $_POST directly and still have the problem. Does anyone know if codeigniter modifies $_POST?

Comment: `%12` is a control character. Why would it be part of a giftcard number?

Comment: Is `%120213001` a valid giftcard number? What have you tried? Please expand your question.

Comment: So the gift card number should be `%120213001?`? Then you didn't properly encode you data.

Comment: I thought I had solution for that, but I was wrong. I've tried it and can only say that the problem isn't reproducable for me

Comment: the % and ? are control characters when swiping a the gift card using a card swipe. Obvioulsy I don't want to have these in the database because they aren't really part of the number

Comment: So the problem is that you are sending data you don't want *and* not encoding it property. Encode the data properly and strip out the unwanted characters at before or after you send it.

Comment: I have determined that it is something to do with codeigniter because it works as expected without it.

Comment: Are you using `xss` filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The % character is used in [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  So you either need to remove the % before sending the string to the server (which is what I would recommend), or else URL-encode the string and deal with the extra characters on the server end.

CodeIgniter is doing the perfectly logical thing in removing the %12, since it appears to be a URL-encoded control character.

Comment: I ended up removing it in javascript before sending it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tracked the problem down to system/core/common.php --> remove_invisible_characters

```
function remove_invisible_characters($str, $url_encoded = TRUE)
{
    $non_displayables = array();

    // every control character except newline (dec 10)
    // carriage return (dec 13), and horizontal tab (dec 09)

    if ($url_encoded)
    {
        $non_displayables[] = '/%0[0-8bcef]/';  // url encoded 00-08, 11, 12, 14, 15
        $non_displayables[] = '/%1[0-9a-f]/';   // url encoded 16-31
    }

    $non_displayables[] = '/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]+/S';   // 00-08, 11, 12, 14-31, 127

    do
    {
        $str = preg_replace($non_displayables, '', $str, -1, $count);
    }
    while ($count);

    return $str;
}
```

Can anyone think of a workaround? Do you consider this a bug in the framework?

EDIT: A way to get the raw value without is to use the $_REQUEST variable

Comment: Using $_REQUEST is great tip! Thanks!